# Get Data from MS Access Database into List<> in C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Current now i have a List<> of data store string called Diff_ProductName.

```
List<string[]> Diff_ProductName = ("SELECT GUID,ProductName FROM Table_A bla bla bla.... ");
```

So i need to use GUID from Diff_ProductName to copy another data from another Table.

```
For (int i = 0; i < Diff_ProductName; i++)
{    
List<string[]> DCB_CopyData = ("SELECT Name, ID FROM Table_B WHERE='"+(((string[])Diff_ProductName[i])[0]+"'");
}
```

The problems is, every GUID got a few ID and Name. Mean :

```
TABLE_B

    GUID      Name     ID
    1          A       012
    1          B       013
    1          c       014
    2          AB      015
    3          D       016
    3          E       017
    4          ACE     018
    4          ADE     019
```

so when i run the program. The data store at DCB_CopyDate only the last GUID data. Mean at DCB_CopyData only have :

```
   GUI   Name      ID
    4     ACE     018
    4     ADE     019
```

So whats the problems with my code? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a query for each GUID and this is painful if your list is really long.
You could simply execute one query like this

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.* FROM Table_A AS ta
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS tb ON ta.GUID = tb.GUID
```

About your code: if you're showing us pseudo-code ok, if not your second query seems really wrong sintactically.